# HTML , CSS: Table doesn't make my page resize accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently downloaded a very simple template for my website.
It contains 1) a simple `style.css` and 2) an example `index.php`
On my attempt to edit that `index.php` and add a table, on the `<div class="main_body">` area, the main content (main body) area, **does't resize the height of the page accordingly**.
However, page resizes just fine with `<p>` , `<h1>` tags , etc. The problem occurs only with tables.
Notice that i have tried to make it rezise with a couple of ways:

- `#main .main_body {height:auto;}`  code in: `style.css` *97th line.*
- `table #displayblocktest {display: inline-block;}`  code: `style.css` *2nd line.*

I uploaded everything on http://jsfiddle.net/48dog2sj/.
So, my question is, what changes do i need to make in order to make my page resize accordingly to tables size ?
Hopefully someone knows a way around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the `align=left`--it's changing the default wrapping around the table: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_align.asp. Furthermore, it's deprecated; you should use the CSS float property instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48dog2sj/1/

Comment: removing align left  indeed solves the problem, can you explain what you meant with css float property ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float for an explanation. Basically, it takes an element out of the normal flow and sticks it to the right and the left, which can also affect the size of the parent element. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/to10tb4v/, you'll see it has the same problem as your original question. Anyway, the old presentational attributes that would be placed within the HTML tags, such as align, have been deprecated for some time. You should use CSS for all styling.

Comment: um , i think i see what you mean , but then how am i supposed to align it to the left in this particular case ?

Comment: It looks like it's already aligned to the left of your div, though if you'd rather it align to the left of the text I'd just use margins.

Comment: yea its on the left indeed , because of the display as block.. so i guess its fine, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `align=left` off the table element!